# is there any of passing flashvars in static publishing method of SWF_Object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swfobject

Well i just want to know that using static publishing method SWF-Object , can we pass flashvars to flash swf file??

The static publish method is

```
<head>
    <title>SWFObject 2 static publishing example page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="embedswf/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "embedswf/expressInstall.swf");
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>   
        <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="600" height="750" flashvars="var1=irfan" params="var1=irfan">
            <param name="movie" value="fish.swf" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="fish.swf" width="600" height="750" flashvars="var1=irfan" params="var1=irfan">
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <div>
                <h1>Alternative content</h1>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
            </div>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
```

but the flashvars and params are not passed to flash file??

Comment: Could you send me a link to what a "static publishing method" is, so I can help you out a little better?

Comment: i should use this <param name="flashvars" value="var1=irfan&amp" /> instead of  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="fish.swf" width="600" height="750" flashvars="var1=irfan" params="var1=irfan">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is if you've got a statically embedded SWF using SWFObject.... thats about the only way that really makes sense. In that case the answer is yes. Even if your embed tag was dynamically generated using PHP or something, you can still pass flash vars. Easiest way to do this is to download and install the swfObject AIR app for generating your embed tag.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/list

You'll see an area for flashvars. It's simply key/value pairs so create a key, "keyname" and populate it with your data. Then in AS3 inside your main class (or anywhere really) you can access this data like so:

```
root.loaderInfo.parameters.keyname;
```

So lets say you have a key "userName" with the value "myUser". You can get this like so:

```
var uName:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.userName;
trace(uName);
```

Obviously you're gonna want to do some basic checking to ensure these objects exist and what not, but this is pretty much how you access flash vars, and also happens to be the same way you access GET variables on the SWF url.

Answer (score 3):

When using static publishing, you need to include the `<param>` nodes (be sure to include a copy for each object):

```
<object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="600" height="750">
    <param name="movie" value="fish.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="var1=irfan&var2=whatever" />

    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="fish.swf" width="600" height="750">
       <param name="flashvars" value="var1=irfan&var2=whatever" />
       <!--<![endif]-->

       <div>
          <h1>Alternative content</h1>
          <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
       </div>

    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Comment: Uhh... not sure why I was marked down, considering it's the correct answer. If you want to include flashvars when embedding a SWF using SWFObject's static publishing, you must use the <param> element, and you must include it for each <object>. Am I missing something?

Comment: no, i do not know who has marked you down and why?? but your answer is correct.